# Convert two strings and compare them with each other

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I used two strings, one for today's date and one for the database, which is the date that users register. I want to convert these two strings to a solar date and compare them.

### This code works well and I converted the first variable correctly and I can compare it

```
 PersianDateTime now = PersianDateTime.Now;
 string s = now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
PersianDateTime persianDate = PersianDateTime.Parse(s);
```

---

### But this code gives an error because it becomes a condition

```
 var ActivitysNotToDo = _context.Activitys.Where(a => a.MasoolAghdamUserID == user.Id && PersianDateTime.Parse(a.ActvityAghdamDate) < persianDate).ToList();
```

---

An error occurred in this code. Please also see the photo

```
PersianDateTime.Parse(a.ActvityAghdamDate)
```

[image]

Comment: Just add the optional parameters to the method call.

Comment: Usability parameter of this +, -,>, <, =>, = <, ==, and =! It has operators, but because I convert it into a condition, it gives an error

Comment: PersianDateTime  is not convertible function for Ef and SQl . please see other vise. convert all Persian date to  Gregorian date then compare them on sql

Comment: Hi @stoofrisat, what is your `PersianDateTime`? Could you pls share with us?

Comment: @Rena PersianDateTime is class for convert datetime to Iranian locale datetime. Persian is most Iranian language.

Comment: Hi @stoofrisat, could you pls share the model? Actually I have tried and works fine. And guess from the visual studio high light, your PersianDateTime does not look like a model. It is more like an struct.

Comment: public String ActvityAghdamDate { get; set; }

Comment: @Rena
If I do this conversion outside the weher condition, it is not a problem and I can compare these two dates, but because inside a condition where I do this, I get an error.

Comment: @Rena Please help

Comment: Hi @stoofrisat, so you still get the error like screenshot and even cannot be compiled? What's your version of asp.net core? Actually, if you use more than ef core 3.0, although this compiled error can disappear, but it still will get runtime error. Because implicit client evaluation has been disabled from EF Core 3, you will get the `The LINQ expression 'xxxx' could not be translated.` error in runtime. So you can only  do where condition outside the linq.

Comment: So how i can do where condition outside the linq Please write the code for me. Thank you

Comment: Because I want a list of data related to this date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit client evaluation has been disabled from EF Core 3. You can change your code like below:

```
var data= _context.Activitys.Where(a => a.MasoolAghdamUserID == user.Id)
                               .AsEnumerable();
var ActivitysNotToDo = data.Where(a => PersianDateTime.Parse(a.ActvityAghdamDate)<persianDate)
                               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first code works for you, then:

Maybe you can modify this line:

```
var ActivitysNotToDo = _context.Activitys.Where(a => a.MasoolAghdamUserID == user.Id && PersianDateTime.Parse(a.ActvityAghdamDate) < persianDate).ToList();
```

For this:

```
var ActivitysNotToDo = _context.Activitys.Where(a => a.MasoolAghdamUserID == user.Id && PersianDateTime.Parse(Convert.ToDateTime(a.ActvityAghdamDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")) < persianDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse();` function need string parameter so you have to pass string parameter in  your expression.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
 string s = now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
 DateTime.Parse(s);

 DateTime.Parse(now.ToString()); // Conversion required
```

Try following code.

```
PersianDateTime.Parse(a.ActvityAghdamDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
or 
PersianDateTime.Parse(Covert.ToDateTime(a.ActvityAghdamDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

Comment: This did not work either

Answer (score -1):

The C# `Compare()` method is used to compare first string with second string lexicographically. If both strings are equal, it returns 0.